# Using python 3 to detect PowerSaveMode or screensaver state in Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: qdbus

How do i monitor dbus messages for when the screen goes black ?

below is the output from dbus-monitor

```
signal time=1699887162.074353 sender=:1.12288 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2006 path=/org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "PowerSaveMode"
         variant             int32 3
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

and

```
signal time=1699887179.300585 sender=:1.12288 -> destination=(null destination) serial=2009 path=/org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "PowerSaveMode"
         variant             int32 0
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```